# Setting custom border using sublass of UILabel in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, subclass

I have created a subclass of UILabel for custom bottom border. The subclass is:
import UIKit

```
class BottomBorderClass: UILabel {


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.setBottomBorder()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        self.setBottomBorder()
    }

    func setBottomBorder()
    {

    self.text = "TITLE LABEL"
        self.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        let layer:CALayer = self.layer
        let bottomBorder:CALayer = CALayer.init(layer: layer)
        bottomBorder.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        bottomBorder.borderWidth = 2;
        bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(-1, self.layer.frame.size.height-1, 
        self.layer.frame.size.width, 2);
        bottomBorder.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)

    }
  }
```

In view controller i am calling the class on @IBOutlet weak var someLabel:BottomBorderClass

The problem is the border and text is not getting displayed. Please help!! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you used IBDesignable for the BottomBorderClass ?

Comment: If you are using storyboards: Do you set the `Custom Class` in the `Identity Insprector`?

Comment: Check my answer.If it's helpful don't forget to click on up arrow and check sign. :)

Comment: @niggeulimann  I jus forgot to that exact basic step. Thanks a lot. I set the class to BottomBorder Class and it works fine, ::) Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your function like this.

```
func setBottomBorder(){

    let borderWidth:CGFloat = 4.0 //Change this according to your needs
    let lineView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y:self.frame.size.height - borderWidth , width: self.frame.size.width, height: borderWidth))
    lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    self.addSubview(lineView)

}
```

From your attribute inspector, don't forget to change class like this.

[image]

**output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks man. I just missed one step, i have updated it in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension for CALayer

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension CALayer {

    func addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge, color: UIColor, thickness: CGFloat) {

        let border = CALayer()

        switch edge {
        case UIRectEdge.top:
            border.frame = CGRect.zero
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: thickness)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.bottom:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height - thickness, width: self.bounds.width, height: thickness)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.left:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: thickness, height: self.bounds.height)
            break
        case UIRectEdge.right:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: self.bounds.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height: self.bounds.height)
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor;

        self.addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

and in your controller, for exemple :

```
@IBOutlet weak var someLabel: UILabel !
someLabel.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.red, thickness: 2)
```

with this method you can use addBorder function with any UILabel, UIButton, ...